Animate instances on multiple curves in geometry nodes
I'm working on a tool for animating simple traffic with three curves. The cars start on one curve and then either keep going straight onto another or turn right onto the third curve. I have this kind-of working although it's not great because there can easily be cars running into each other the way it's set up now.
But my more pressing challenge is I want to be able to set the cars that are turning right to a different speed as soon as they go onto that curve.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that or if it's even possible with my current setup. Sorry for such a general question but I'm open to any suggestions for how to achieve this. 


